# How to group all string values to one cell in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i have entry's like this.

```
Projects Persons
Project1 Person1
Project1 Person2
Project1 Person3
Project2 Person1
```

And i need an output like this:

```
Project1 Person1,Preson2,Person3
Project2 Person1
```

How can i do this using mySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT Projects,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Persons
  ORDER BY Persons SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM <your_table_name>
  GROUP BY Projects;
```